# Excel: how to "connect" cells in 2 tables while sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

I have 2 tables and I need to make some relations between cells in these tables so when I sort data in the 1st table the data in the 2nd table would sort accordingly. I try to illustrate my problem.
Suppose there are 6 players (bike racing) and there 4 rounds of competitions. In each round the winner gets 10 points, 2nd place - 5 points, 3rd place - 1 point, 4-6 - zero points. 
So in the 1st table there are the points for each player in each round.
In the 2nd table there are positions each player finished
See picture 1

[image: Picture 1. before sorting]

Then I want to sort by the total points to see who is the champion. But I also want that when I sort table 1 by the total points the data in Table 2  would sort accordingly so I see the positions of each player correctly.
I want this to look like on the picture 2.

[image: Picture 2]

Any thoughts? IMO it shoukd be something really simple but I could't think of anything

Answer (score 0):

You can put "=A2" in A11 cell, then drag until E16.

That should work. Hope it helps. (: